How to create a continous conversation between two OpenAI chatbots
I want two independent instances of OpenAI chatbots to play a wordgame via python API. At this moment I only know how to create a single instance and ask it a single set of user messages. I thus have two main considerations:

how can I have an ongoing conversation with a given instance? it seems like this was an option before with chat_completion::send_message method, but it is not avaiable anymore in the last version of the API and I only seem to be able to pass messages upon ::create method. According to OpenAI API continuing conversation in a dialogue instead of passing a new message to the existing instance, one should create a new instance for every new message and just provide it with the whole previous history of conversation. Which is a very expensive way to use the API as it seems. Did anything change perhaps? the quoted question is a bit old
how can I create two independent instances that do not share the information that I told them privately. Say, I tell the first one that my name is Alice and the second one that my age is 20. I don't want the first one to know that my age is 20 and the second one to think that my name is Alice. After some internet search I've found that people suggest to use different API keys for every independent instance, but if to send the new message I have to re-create instance every time, perhaps this is not necessary at all


Your best bet is to use langchain, and initialize two different conversation chains, using two different instances of ConversationBufferMemory(), in order to retain different memories. You can then decide how to handle the back and forth between the two bot, changing the behavior inside the loop
from langchain_community.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import ConversationChain
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory

number_of_turns = 5
llm_model = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-4o-mini", openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY)

# initialize two different memories for the two bot
bot1_memory = ConversationBufferMemory()
bot2_memory = ConversationBufferMemory()

# Create two conversation chains with separate memories
bot1_chain = ConversationChain(llm=llm_model, memory=bot1_memory)
bot2_chain = ConversationChain(llm=llm_model, memory=bot2_memory)

# Start messages for each bot
bot1_start = (
    "I want to play a game with you: ... my word start with a, can you guess it?"
)
bot2_start = (
    "I want to play a game with you too: ...my word start with b, can you guess it?"
)

# first turn
bot1_reply = bot1_chain.run(input=bot1_start)
print(f"Bot 1: {bot1_reply}")
bot2_reply = bot2_chain.run(input=bot2_start)
print(f"Bot 2: {bot2_reply}")

# loop for as many turns as you want
for turn in range(number_of_turns):
    print(f"Turn number {turn}")
    bot1_reply = bot1_chain.run(input=bot2_reply)
    print(f"Bot 1: {bot1_reply}")
    bot2_reply = bot2_chain.run(input=bot1_reply)
    print(f"Bot 2: {bot2_reply}")

